# django set global variable in template

Tags: html, django, templates, variables

I am using a banner image that needs to change on each page, I would like to set the banner in the html template, so that it is easy for the person I am building it for to easily add new pages.

I am developing it in django, but I can't figure out how to get it to work, please help!

example:

**index.html**

```
set image url here
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

**base.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    {% include 'top.html %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**top.html**

```
<div>
  <img src="{{ image url }}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django template language does not let you set variables. You can acheive something similar by using blocks. Change your base template to:

## base.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="{% block image_url %}/default_image.jpg{% endblock %}">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then override the `image_url` block in your templates, e.g.

## index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block image_url %}/images/index.jpg{% endblock %}
```

Note that with this approach it is not possible to use `{% include top.html %}`, because you cannot override blocks that have been included by the `{% include %}` tag.

Comment: Hi Alasdair ... i was afraid of that. Django just keep on disappointing! ... but thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

well I didn't understand very well, but should be better if you delete top.html and include that content in the base like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="{% block url_img %}{% enblock %}">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in your index

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block url_img %}here images url{% endblock %}
```

also if you are using top.html for another purpose, do the same:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block url_img %}{{ image url }}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi Mauricio ... tried what u suggested and it does not work! all i get is src=""

Comment: then there is a problem with the block, create a empty block inside the div and paste all the <img> tag with the url obviously